# I am getting error for the Language Setting in fastlane when i trying to capture screenshots using Screengrab

Tags: android, fastlane, fastlane-snapshot

I am getting the error in the `takeScreenShot()` and it also give me the error of language configuration while executing the command `fastlane Screengrab`

Here is my test **Execution Code**

```
/**
 * Instrumentation test, which will execute on an Android device.
 *
 */
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {

    @ClassRule
    public static final LocaleTestRule localeTestRule = new LocaleTestRule();

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> activityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);


    @Test
    public void testTakeScreenshot() {
        Screengrab.screenshot("Dashboard");
    }

    @Test
    public void useAppContext() {
    }
}
```

**Error in terminal :-**

> [11:09:17]: ▸ com.tcc.gstknowledge.ExampleInstrumentedTest:
>   [11:09:17]: ▸ Error in
>   testTakeScreenshot(com.tcc.gstknowledge.ExampleInstrumentedTest):
>   [11:09:17]: ▸ java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't get the
>   activity from the view context [11:09:17]: ▸ at
>   tools.fastlane.screengrab.DecorViewScreenshotStrategy$ScreenshotViewAction.perform(DecorViewScreenshotStrategy.java:69)
>   [11:09:17]: ▸ at
>   android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:356)
>   [11:09:17]: ▸ at
>   android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:248)
>   [11:09:17]: ▸ at
>   android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.access$100(ViewInteraction.java:63)
>   [11:09:17]: ▸ at
>   android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:153)
>   [11:09:17]: ▸ at
>   android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:150)
>   [11:09:17]: ▸ at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) [11:09:17]: ▸
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) [11:09:17]: ▸
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) [11:09:17]: ▸
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) [11:09:17]: ▸ at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) [11:09:17]:
>   ▸ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) [11:09:17]: ▸ at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518)
>   [11:09:17]: ▸ at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
>   [11:09:19]: ▸ . [11:09:19]: ▸ Time: 5.788 [11:09:19]: ▸ There was 1
>   failure: [11:09:19]: ▸ 1)
>   testTakeScreenshot(com.tcc.gstknowledge.ExampleInstrumentedTest)
>   [11:09:19]: ▸ java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't get the
>   activity from the view context [11:09:19]: ▸ at
>   tools.fastlane.screengrab.DecorViewScreenshotStrategy$ScreenshotViewAction.perform(DecorViewScreenshotStrategy.java:69)
>   [11:09:19]: ▸ at
>   android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:356)
>   [11:09:19]: ▸ at
>   android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:248)
>   [11:09:19]: ▸ at
>   android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.access$100(ViewInteraction.java:63)
>   [11:09:19]: ▸ at
>   android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:153)
>   [11:09:19]: ▸ at
>   android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:150)
>   [11:09:19]: ▸ at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) [11:09:19]: ▸
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) [11:09:19]: ▸
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) [11:09:19]: ▸
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) [11:09:19]: ▸ at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) [11:09:19]:
>   ▸ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) [11:09:19]: ▸ at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518)
>   [11:09:19]: ▸ at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
>   [11:09:19]: ▸ FAILURES!!! [11:09:19]: ▸ Tests run: 2,  Failures: 1
>
> [!] Tests failed for locale en-US on device 3300dea196566381

Comment: Tried setting the default strategy? https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/android/screenshots/#improved-screenshot-capture-with-ui-automator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will probably help:

> As of screengrab 0.5.0, you can specify different strategies to control the way screengrab captures screenshots. The newer strategy delegates to UI Automator which fixes a number of problems compared to the original strategy:
>
> - Shadows/elevation are correctly captured for Material UI
> - Multi-window situations are correctly captured (dialogs, etc.)
> - Works on Android N
>
> However, UI Automator requires a device with API level >= 18, so it is not yet the default strategy. To enable it for all screenshots by default, make the following call before your tests run:
>
> ```
>  Screengrab.setDefaultScreenshotStrategy(new UiAutomatorScreenshotStrategy());
> ```

https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/android/screenshots/#improved-screenshot-capture-with-ui-automator

Comment: The key seems to be the line of code at the end of that quote from the docs.